# Visual Studio 2013 can't open project of windows phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, sdk

I have the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK on my dev pc installed together with VS 2013 Community Update 4. I need to open some WP 8.0 projects, but I can't do that without having WP 8.0 SDK installed, give me that error:

[image]

I tryed to download the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 from Microsoft site but when I lunch the istaller give me that error:

[image]

How can I resolve that problem? If I go to the link didn't explain nothing.

Regards,
Roberto

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 PRO

Comment: 86x version... I forgot it excuse me

Comment: You cannot fly to mars without a rocket ship. "How do I fly to mars then?" You don't.  Unless you hit Elon Musk over the head and take his.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is self-explanatory, you need a 64bit OS (x64) but you are running a 32bit one (x86).

Comment: But i can't istall in my computer a 64bit OS. I can't work for that reason?

Comment: if you cannot install Windows 8.1 Pro x64 then your are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason why this happens is because your VS2013 version is x86 and you downloaded the x64 version of WP8 SDK.

Try the following instead of downloading the SDK and manually installing it.

1. Right-Click on Start Button
2. Open Programs and Features.
3. Find Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.
4. Click on it and Click Change.
5. Select Modify.
6. Choose the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK from there and click Update.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I try like that, but there is not the choice for Windows Phone 8.0 SDK.

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Strange it should have that option in your programs and features. try installing the express edition of the sdk: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471